# Method in bean that checks whether a row in a Primefaces datatable is still being edited

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

In a JSF and Primefaces based Java application, I have a table, where the user can dynamically add rows so as to add comments.

Here is the code for a table with comments. Comments can be added by pressing a button. Pressing the button will add a comment to the top of the table.
Everything works fine if the user presses the check icon to save the text entered into a new row. However, when saving the whole page (code not included), only the author and date fields will be saved. Any entered text is lost.

I am trying to find a way to find out, whether a row in a Primefaces datatable is still being edited, so as to either save it, or show a warning to the user.

This is the xhtml:

```
<div class="ui-g-6 no-vertical-padding">
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{commentController.initPage()}"/>
    <h:form id="CommentsForm">
        <p:commandButton style="width: 1px; height: 1px; position: fixed; top: -1000px;"
                         action="#{mainController.save}" styleClass="cleanDirtyButton"/>
        <p:fieldset legend="Comments" style="height: 309px">
            <p:remoteCommand name="onCellEdit" update="commentTable" partialSubmit="true"
                             ignoreAutoUpdate="true"/>

            <!--<h:inputHidden id="hiddenSizeId" value="#{commentForm.itemsSize}"/>-->
            <!--<h:inputHidden id="hiddenIxId" value="#{commentForm.newItemIx}"/>-->

            <!-- workarround -->
            <h:inputHidden id="hiddenSizeId" value="1000000"/>
            <h:inputHidden id="hiddenIxId" value="999999"/>

            <script type="text/JavaScript">
                function getNewItemPos() {

                    var noOfItems = $("#CommentsForm\\:hiddenSizeId").val();
                    var itemIx = $("#CommentsForm\\:hiddenIxId").val();


                    var bucketHt = $("#CommentsForm\\:commentTable .ui-datatable-scrollable-body").height();
                    var scrollHt = $("#CommentsForm\\:commentTable .ui-datatable-scrollable-body").prop("scrollHeight");

                    var itemHt = parseInt(scrollHt) / parseInt(noOfItems);
                    var noItemsInBucket = parseInt(bucketHt) / parseFloat(itemHt);

                    var itemNo = parseInt(itemIx) + 1;
                    var targetBucket = parseInt(itemNo) / parseFloat(noItemsInBucket);
                    var halfBucketHt = parseInt(bucketHt) / 2;

                    var scrollPos =
                            (parseInt(bucketHt) * (parseFloat(targetBucket) - 1)) + parseFloat(halfBucketHt);
                    var scrollPosInt = Math.round(parseFloat(scrollPos));

                    $('#CommentsForm\\:commentTable .ui-datatable-scrollable-body').animate({scrollTop: scrollPosInt});
                }

                function setCellFocus() {
                    $('.focus_comment:visible').delay().focus();
                }

                function cellEdit() {
                    setTimeout(setCellFocus, 1500);
                    $('.editTable .ui-datatable-data tr').last().find('span.ui-icon-pencil').each(function () {
                        jQuery(this).click()
                    });
                }

            </script>

            <p:dataTable id="commentTable"
                         widgetVar="commentTableWidget"
                         value="#{projectForm.project.Comments}"
                         sortOrder="DESCENDING"
                         sortBy="#{comment.changedOn}"
                         var="comment"
                         editable="true"
                         rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                         resizableColumns="true"
                         scrollable="true"
                         scrollRows="10"
                         liveScroll="true"
                         scrollHeight="212"
                         style="margin-top: 5px;"
                         emptyMessage="No comment found"
                         styleClass="ui-corner-all plus-button editTable noBackground">

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton id="addlink"
                                     action="#{commentController.addComment()}"
                                     oncomplete="getNewItemPos();cellEdit();setCellFocus();"
                                     disabled="#{commentForm.editMode or !pR.hasPermission('PROJECTS:write')}"
                                     process="@this"
                                     partialSubmit="true"
                                     update="commentTable"
                                     value="Add Comment"
                                     styleClass="table-plus-button"
                                     icon="fa fa-plus" iconPos="right">
                        <p:ajax update=":CommentsForm:commentTable :CommentsForm:hiddenIxId :CommentsForm:hiddenSizeId"/>
                    </p:commandButton>

                </f:facet>

                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{commentController.onRowEdit}"
                        update="commentTable"
                        oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) {onCellEdit();} else {$('.editTable tbody.ui-datatable-data tr td .deleteButton').hide();}"/>
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{commentController.onRowCancel}"
                        onsuccess="onCellEdit();" update="commentTable"/>
                <p:ajax event="rowEditInit" listener="#{commentForm.setEditMode(true)}"
                        update="addlink"
                        onstart="$('.editTable tbody.ui-datatable-data tr td .ui-icon-pencil').hide();$('.editTable tbody.ui-datatable-data tr td .deleteButton').hide();"/>

                <p:column width="18%" headerText="date" sortBy="#{comment.changedOn}"
                          styleClass="align-top"
                          sortOrder="DESCENDING">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comment.changedOn eq null ?
                                 (comment.createdOn eq null ? '': comment.createdOn ) : comment.changedOn}">
                        <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" timeZone="CET"/>
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>

                <p:column width="30%" headerText="Text">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <span style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
                                <h:outputText escape="true" style="white-space:pre-line;"
                                              id="commentDisplay"
                                              value="#{comment.text.length() > 200 ? comment.text.substring(0, 200).concat(' ...'): comment.text}">
                                </h:outputText>
                                <p:tooltip id="commentDisplayToolTip"
                                           for="commentDisplay,commentDisplayToolTipTxt"
                                           rendered="#{comment.text.length() gt 200}"
                                           beforeShow="$('.ui-tooltip:visible').hide()"
                                           myPosition="left bottom" atPosition="right bottom"
                                           hideDelay="500">
                                    <p:outputLabel id="commentDisplayToolTipTxt"
                                                   styleClass="scrollOutputLabel"
                                                   value="#{comment.text}"/>
                                </p:tooltip>
                            </span>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:message for="text" id="nameMsg"/>
                            <p:inputTextarea value="#{comment.text}" id="text"
                                             onkeypress="setConfirmUnload(true); if ((($.browser.mozilla &amp;&amp; event.ctrlKey &amp;&amp; event.keyCode==13) ||(($.browser.msie||$.browser.chrome) &amp;&amp; event.ctrlKey))
                                             &amp;&amp; ( ! (event.altKey &amp;&amp; event.ctrlKey) ) )
                            {$('.editTable tbody.ui-datatable-data tr td .ui-icon-check:visible').click();  $('#buttonForm\\:speichern').addClass('unsaved'); setConfirmUnload(true); }"
                                             title="Text"
                                             styleClass="Wid90 input_mandatory focus_comment">
                            </p:inputTextarea>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column width="30%" headerText="author" sortBy="#{comment.changedBy}"
                          styleClass="align-top"
                          sortOrder="DESCENDING">
                    <h:outputText
                            value="#{comment.changedBy eq null ?
                        ( comment.createdBy eq null ?  '' : commentController.extractUserData(comment.createdBy))
                        :commentController.extractUserData(comment.changedBy)}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column width="83" id="editor" styleClass="NoPadding align-top">
                    <p:rowEditor/>
                    <h:panelGroup id="deleteSpan">
                        <p:commandButton id="delete" partialSubmit="true"
                                         style="height: 41px;"
                                         title="Löschen"
                                         action="#{commentController.removeComment(comment)}"
                                         update="commentTable"
                                         process="@this commentTable"
                                         immediate="true"
                                         icon="fa fa-close"
                                         iconPos="center"
                                         styleClass="deleteButton Fright"
                                         disabled="#{empty commentForm.project.Comments}">
                            <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Delete Comment?"
                                       icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:fieldset>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

And this is the Controller:

```
@Named("commentController")
@RequestScoped
public class CommentController {

    // this method is executed when pressing the add-comment button:
    public void addComment() {
        Comment comment = new Comment();
        commentForm.setComment(comment);
        final DataTable commentTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("commentsForm:commentTable");
        if (commentTable != null) {
            commentTable.setValueExpression("sortBy", null);
            commentTable.setValueExpression("sortOrder", null);
        }
        comment.setProject(projectForm.getProject);
        projectForm.getProject().getComments().add(comment);
        if (commentTable) {
            commentTable.processValidators(getFacesContext());
        }
    }

    // not really relevant for my question, because:
    //  this method is only called when properly ending the rowEdit by pressing the green check
    public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        Comment comment = (Comment) event.getObject();
        if (!validateComment(comment)) {
            getFacesContext().validationFailed();
        } else {
            if (comment.getId() != 0 && commentForm.getProject().getComments().contains(comment)) {
                projectForm.getProject().getComments().set(commentForm.getProject().getComments().indexOf(comment), comment);
            }
            commentForm.setEditMode(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by adding `<p:ajax update="commentTable"/>` to the `<p:inputTextarea...>`after finding this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44710044/6426882

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by adding

```
<p:ajax update="commentTable"/>
```

to the

```
<p:inputTextarea...>
```

after finding this post: [stackoverflow.com/a/44710044/6426882](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44710044/6426882)